# How to protect folders in public_html from visitors

Tags: javascript, php

I need to keep all my files and folders of my website in public_html folder. There are some folders for javascript codes like 'Javascript' and css codes like 'CSS', 'Images' for images, etc. It is easy for any visitor to type just the folder address like 'http://www.website.com/Javascript' and he will have permission to see all my javascript codes. I want to restrict these folders from visitors and use only for my scripts which are uploaded in public_html folder. How can this be done? Please give solution for my scripts in public_html also, which will need to access those folders.

Comment: you can minify & uglify the js code

Comment: _"How can this be done?"_ It can't be. JS and CSS files are rendered client side. You can not prevent people from being able to access them and still expect your site to work.

Comment: I just do not want them to enter my folder. It will not be a problem if they can see javascript files of the page they are browsing. But I want to limit access of viewers to the entire folder where I keep all my codes. @Alex

Comment: If you just want to disable directory listings, then you want `Options -Indexes`. But note this will *not* disable the ability to download the files if you know the name, and will not prevent people from being able to see the source code of your site.

Comment: Then what is the proper solution? How can I prevent these files from being downloaded? Please write in brief.@AlexHowansky

Comment: I'll say it again -- you can not. Any JS and CSS files that your web site uses will be publicly available, that's how the Internet works.

Comment: "I just do not want them to enter my folder." - add empty index.php to each folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your security purpose you can set access permission for the public access for particular files, folder etc with the apache .htaccess file.

In your case create .htaccess file in the folder name public_html and put the bellow htaccess configuration:

Completely restricted from web server.

```
Deny from all
```

Restrict folder, sever can access files.

```
Options -Indexes
```

This works for me.

Comment: Erm... this will shut down your whole site.

Comment: Actually it worked when I put the .htaccess file in the folder which I wanted to protect and put the code 'Deny from all' in it.
I'm not sure, but I think this will work.

Comment: Sure, but now those files can not be loaded from web pages that reference them.

Comment: Yeah @john, this will protect particular folder only. if you want to configure for entire site you have to configure in the root folder.

Comment: Alex, do you know any other way to protect my folders? If yes, please share.

Comment: This system 'Deny from all' also denies access request of the server. It is a problem.